# Get Calendar ID of Event in Google Calendar API C#

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Is there a way to get the Calendar ID of an event in Google Calendar through the Event class?

```
        var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = "1079676878296-hga8cb7jgk2lmprishaiiul8vkutu33b.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            ClientSecret = "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",
        },
        new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar },
        CalendarAccount,
        CancellationToken.None).Result;

        var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Custom CRM",
        });

        var recurringEvent = service.Events.Get(eventid);

        recurringEvent.Execute().Summary
```

Like where I can do **recurringEvent.Execute().Summary**,

Is there a way to do **recurringEvent.Execute().CalendarID**?

Comment: Well, you're going to start by expiring those credentials and generating new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execute method returns the [event object](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events#resource).

```
var result = recurringEvent.Execute();
result.Id
```